# HTML Comment after </html>

Tags: html, comments

Is this safe for most modern browsers or will it turn into a huge abomination?

eg:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Please work</title>
</head>
<body>
My Awesome Body
</body>
</html>
<!-- Generated in 1.337 seconds -->
```

Comment: You can add comment wherever you want\

Comment: I'm not sure it would case any problems, but I also don't think that's valid HTML.

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault except above the doctype, that confuses browsers, and might even trigger qwirks mode

Comment: Amazon does this to place a meowing duck at the end of it's source code. view-source:https://www.amazon.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that, as long as you keep the `DOCTYPE` declaration at the very top of the page, you shouldn't have any issue with placing comments anywhere you want.
Although, it is best to always try for different browsers.

Comment: This says it all. Now if only I could skip the 10 minutes I have to wait and accept your answer.

Comment: @root Why do you think so?

Comment: @JonasKaufmann `if only I could skip the 10 minutes` And then, ten minutes later, there you were! Welcome to the future, intrepid adventurer. Much has changed since your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check it with a [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Just did, it's valid. I used validator.w3.org.

Answer (score 1):

Either check it with a validator or run your code personally through all the available web browsers, always the best way to go about that!

However, you should be fine as long as you avoid putting code above the `"<!DOCTYPE>"` line

Answer (score 0):

it will work but Im not sure it is valid html.
You can run an html code without the `<html>` tag at all, the browsers will still accept it.
But its not good practice. try keep your html code valid

Comment: It's still valid according to validator.w3.org